# Delete all tuples from a list, if the first two elements of another tuple matches

Tags: python, list, tuples, element

i have two tuple lists, and i want to delete all tuples from list1, if the first two elements of a tuple from list2 matches with the first two elements of a tuple from list1.

`list1 = [('google', 'data', '1'), ('google', 'data', '2'), ('google', 'data', '3'), ('google', 'data', '4'), ('google', 'WORLD', '1')]`

`list2 = [('google', 'data', '1'), ('google', 'HELLO', '2'), ('google', 'BLA', '3')]`

Result:
`list1 =  [('google', 'WORLD', '1')]`

Comment: make an attempt and provide [mcve] if you have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `all` to get only elements that do not match with any of the elements from the second list.

```py
res = [x for x in list1 if all(x[:2] != y[:2] for y in list2)]
```

Comment: Thank you !!! i was trying for hours and this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first first two elements of each tuple in `list2`, use `set()` to deduplicate entries, then filter elements in `list1` that are not in this set.

```
list1 = [('google', 'data', '1'), ('google', 'data', '2'), ('google', 'data', '3'),
         ('google', 'data', '4'), ('google', 'WORLD', '1')]
list2 = [('google', 'data', '1'), ('google', 'HELLO', '2'), ('google', 'BLA', '3')]

list2_pairs = set(map(lambda tpl: tpl[0:2], list2))
print(list2_pairs)  # {('google', 'BLA'), ('google', 'HELLO'), ('google', 'data')}
list1_result = list(filter(lambda tpl: tpl[0:2] not in list2_pairs, list1))
print(list1_result)  # [('google', 'WORLD', '1')]
```